# Generate the Fibonacci sequence with Accumulate

Tags: functions, function-construction, integer-sequence, list-manipulation

Is there a way to generate the Fibonacci sequence with the `Accumulate` function?

Comment: Generate a specific number, generate up to a specific number ?

Comment: @Sektor For example, generate the first 100 values of the Fibonacci sequence starting with { 0, 1 }

Comment: Ponder on the result of `Accumulate[Fibonacci[Range[-1, 18]]] === Fibonacci[Range[20]]`. You probably would be more interested in `LinearRecurrence[]`.

Answer (score 16):

```
fibSequences[n_?EvenQ] := Nest[Accumulate[Join[{1, 0}, #]] &, {}, n/2]
fibSequences[n_?OddQ] := Most@Nest[Accumulate[Join[{1, 0}, #]] &, {}, (n + 1)/2]
```

---

```
fibSequences[10]
```

> ```
>  {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}
> ```

```
 fibSequences[9]
```

> ```
>  {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34}
> ```

Comment: Nice!  Wish I'd seen that myself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks:)

Comment: Probably a good time for `Nothing`: `Nest[Accumulate[{1, 0} ~Join~ #] &, {If[OddQ[n], 1, Nothing]}, Quotient[n, 2]]`

Comment: @J. M., It is the first time for me to know the *built-in* `Nothing`.Thanks :) I searched the *DOC*, then I known that it was introduced in *V10.2*

Answer (score 6):

Well... I did use `Accumulate`!

```
First /@ NestList[{Last @ #, Last @* Accumulate @ #} &, {0, 1}, 10]
{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}
```